# polynomial $g$:$g(x)=f(f(x))$ then $f$ must be polynomial?

Tags: analysis

**Question :**

given continuous function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)=f(f(x))$.

Suppose $g(x)$ is non-constant polynomial, then $f$ must be polynomial?

---

If $DEG(g)=1$ : $\\$

Set $g(x)=x$ then $f(f(x))=x$.  Solved this functional equation with WA and it gave me some counter-examples like $(1-x^3)^\frac{1}{3}$.

Then how about $DEG(g) > 1$?

This means if $DEG(g)=n$, $$\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k=f(f(x))$$ with real-constant $a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n(a_n\neq0)$.

I can't approach this, just think it is false.
Any hints please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $f(x)=|x|^{\sqrt 2}$?  I get $f(f(x))=|x|^2$ which (as a function on the reals) is the same as $x^2$.

Comment: I think it might be possible to show that if $\deg(g)$ is not a square, then $f$ has no chance of being a polynomial by considerations on the leading coefficient.

Comment: @zwim Go for it!

Comment: @zwim Except that doesn't prove the existence of an $f$.